# Load a UIKit view controller and .xib as an Cocos2D scene

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Hi I'm pretty new to cocos2d and I want the opening screen, lobby ect, to be loaded from a .xib standard uikit style and from there, press 'play' etc, load a regular cocas 2d scene. ANy links or help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks all.

Comment: Hmm I've never done this.  I would also be interested in some recommended links if anyone has some.

Comment: Hmm the question is why you want to do that? Not criticizing you, I'm just curious :)

Comment: I'm not sure about Storms' reasons but personally I just want to know how to do everything :P  I'm a dirty hack kind of programmer and I like to occasionally do things the "wrong way".  I can see how this could be useful in the rare occasion.

Comment: Honestly I'm just more comfortable with the uikit for menu building etc, I'm super visual so it helps me work faster. Or super lazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I've done this I've used the class I found on the following Cocos2D forum thread [CCUIViewWrapper](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/6889). It always works great for me.